# Erro ao fazer insert no BD SQL utilizando JDBC

Tags: sql-server, datetime, jdbc

Necessito fazer um insert utilizando Conexão JDBC, mas ao inserir gera o erro abaixo.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed
>   when converting date and/or time from character string.

Aqui abaixo esta meu Insert.

```
insert into OFOBJOFICINALOCAL (CODCOLIGADA, IDOBJOF, CODLOCAL, DATAENTRADA, DATALANCAMENTO, DATASAIDA, CODUSUARIO, CODMOTIVOTRANSF,
RECCREATEDBY, RECCREATEDON, RECMODIFIEDBY, RECMODIFIEDON) values 
('1', 'CB-01', '2.0334', '07/10/2016 12:54', '2019-3-8T10:48:8',
'null', 'xxxx.xxxx', 'null', 'xxxx.xxxx', '2019-3-8T10:48:8',
'xxxx.xxxx', '2019-3-8T10:48:8')
```

Alguem sabe me dizer como resolvo, porque já tentei de todas as formas alterar essas datas mas não vai...

Comment: **(1)** O valor `07/10/2016 12:54` significa 7 de outubro ou 10 de julho?  **(2)** 'NULL' significa que quer informar ausência de valor *ou* armazenar o string 'null'?

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que em muitos sites é uma prática comum, mas aqui não é necessário. Vc já aceitou uma resposta e isso é o suficiente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro foi causado por valor informado para colunas de data & hora: DATAENTRADA, DATALANCAMENTO, DATASAIDA, RECCREATEDON, RECMODIFIEDON. O mais provável é que seja na parte de segundos do horário `10:48:8`, embora o string `'null'` também esteja errado.

O formato ISO 8601 (aaaa-mm-dd**T**hh:mm:ss) é independente da configuração do SQL Server para `language` e/ou `dateformat`.

Experimente:

```
insert into OFOBJOFICINALOCAL (CODCOLIGADA, IDOBJOF, CODLOCAL, DATAENTRADA, DATALANCAMENTO, DATASAIDA, CODUSUARIO, CODMOTIVOTRANSF,
RECCREATEDBY, RECCREATEDON, RECMODIFIEDBY, RECMODIFIEDON) values 
('1', 'CB-01', '2.0334', '2016-10-07T12:54:00', '2019-03-08T10:48:08',
null, 'xxxx.xxxx', null, 'xxxx.xxxx', '2019-03-08T10:48:08',
'xxxx.xxxx', '2019-03-08T10:48:08')
```

Comment: Realmente, a coluna "null", deve ser inserida sem aspas, obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz:

> ```
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
> ```

Ou em tradução livre:

> ```
> Conversão falhou ao converter data e/ou hora de uma string
> ```

Dependendo da configuração do seu `SQL Server` será considerado o formato `AAAMMDD HH:mm:SS` então você tem duas opções:

- Enviar a data neste formato:

```
INSERT INTO OFOBJOFICINALOCAL(CODCOLIGADA,
                              IDOBJOF,
                              CODLOCAL,
                              DATAENTRADA,
                              DATALANCAMENTO,
                              CODUSUARIO,
                              RECCREATEDBY,
                              RECCREATEDON,
                              RECMODIFIEDBY,
                              RECMODIFIEDON)
                       VALUES('1',
                              'CB-01',
                              '2.0334',
                              '20161007 12:54:00',
                              '20190308 10:48:08',
                              'xxxx.xxxx',
                              'xxxx.xxxx',
                              '20190308 10:48:08',
                              'xxxx.xxxx',
                              '20190308 10:48:08');
```

- Ou como você mesmo informou estar usando um `JDBC` você pode utilizar um `PreparedStatement` passando as variáveis como parâmetro:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tabela(data) VALUES(?)");
ps.setDate(1, data);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```